# Creator CI20: Wrong Image Format for bootm command

Tags: sd-card, u-boot, mips

I am trying to get my Creator CI20 to [boot from sdcard](http://elinux.org/CI20_Dev_Zone#Making_a_bootable_SD_card_from_sources) directly.

I compiled a vanilla Linux kernel 4.9.20 using (I am running debian stretch on my laptop):

```
$ make ARCH=mips ci20_defconfig
$ make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=mipsel-linux-gnu- uImage
Image Name:   Linux-4.9.20
Created:      Sat Jul  1 21:04:19 2017
Image Type:   MIPS Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
Data Size:    5225712 Bytes = 5103.23 kB = 4.98 MB
Load Address: 80010000
Entry Point:  8034d0a0
  Image arch/mips/boot/uImage is ready
```

If I copy the file `arch/mips/boot/uImage` to my [tftp location](http://elinux.org/CI20_Dev_Zone#Loading_the_Linux_Kernel_over_ethernet_via_TFTP), I can manage the kernel to boot properly:

```
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
ci20# dhcp 0x88000000 192.168.0.14:uImage
ERROR: resetting DM9000 -> not responding
dm9000 i/o: 0xb6000000, id: 0x90000a46 
DM9000: running in 8 bit mode
MAC: d0:31:10:ff:7d:02
operating at 100M full duplex mode
BOOTP broadcast 1
DHCP client bound to address 192.168.0.15
Using dm9000 device
TFTP from server 192.168.0.14; our IP address is 192.168.0.15
Filename 'uImage'.
Load address: 0x88000000
Loading: #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     ################################
     264.6 KiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 4924012 (4b226c hex)

## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 88000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-4.9.20
   Image Type:   MIPS Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    4923948 Bytes = 4.7 MiB
   Load Address: 80010000
   Entry Point:  803465e0
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK

Starting k[    0.111767] jz4780-nemc 13410000.nemc: failed to calculate clock period
[    0.148419] UBI error: cannot open mtd 3, error -19[    0.153621] UBI error: cannot open mtd 4, error -19
[    0.158775] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    0.167039] Rebooting in 10 seconds..bootm 0x88000000NAND:  8192 MiB
```

But if I copy it to my sdcard, I get this weird message from u-boot:

```
U-Boot 2013.10-rc3-g25f5638f9 (Jul 01 2017 - 16:30:50)

Board: ci20 (r1) (Ingenic XBurst JZ4780 SoC)
DRAM:  1 GiB
NAND:  8192 MiB
MMC:   jz_mmc msc1: 0
In:    eserial4
Out:   eserial4
Err:   eserial4
Net:   dm9000
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
** File not found /boot/uImage **
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
```

Here is the content of the sdcard:

```
% tree /media/mathieu/466bcc7d-37c4-41f3-b83f-8ac6628eb2bb/boot 
/media/mathieu/466bcc7d-37c4-41f3-b83f-8ac6628eb2bb/boot
├── uImage
└── vmlinux.img

0 directories, 2 files
```

And file system is:

```
% mount
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/mathieu/466bcc7d-37c4-41f3-b83f-8ac6628eb2bb type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Is there a way to get a little bit more information from u-boot on what the error could be ?

Comment: Can you please do a:
% sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mmcblk0p1 | grep features
and see if it says 64bit?  If so, the filesystem is too new for that old of a U-Boot and you need to re-create the boot partition without that flag being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @tom-rini the issue was simply the 64bits in ext4 added automatically.

The documentation from:

- [CI20_Dev_Zone#Making_a_bootable_SD_card_from_sources](http://elinux.org/CI20_Dev_Zone#Making_a_bootable_SD_card_from_sources)

Describes:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdx1
```

instead it should have said (for newer mkfs.ext4 command):

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -O^64bit,^metadata_csum /dev/sdx1
```

Just for posterity, this is the second time I got bitten by this:

- [/pci@f400000/ata-6@d/@0:3,/boot/vmlinux: Unknown or corrupt](https://bugs.debian.org/825110#67)

Hopefully the last.

Comment: I created an account on elinux.org to fix the documentation.